# Reindex dataframe upon exact text match

Tags: python, pandas

I want to create a mapping of indices from one dataframe with another dataframe's indices when the `text` column (given) matches. The length of both the dataframes are equal and there is *always* going to be a full match.

```
df_original = pd.DataFrame(dict(text=['The cat sat on the table', 'There is a kind of hush', 'The boy kicked the ball', 'He shot the elephant', 'I want to eat right now!']))
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(text=['He shot the elephant', 'The boy kicked the ball', 'The cat sat on the table', 'I want to eat right now!', 'There is a kind of hush']))
```

`df_original` looks like:

```
0   The cat sat on the table
1   There is a kind of hush
2   The boy kicked the ball
3   He shot the elephant
4   I want to eat right now!
```

`df` looks like:

```
0   He shot the elephant
1   The boy kicked the ball
2   The cat sat on the table
3   I want to eat right now!
4   There is a kind of hush
```

I want to get the dictionary mapping, like so,

```
d = {2: 0, 4: 1, 1: 2, 0: 3, 3: 4}
```

For eg: the *2nd* index of `df` matches with the *0th* index of `df_original`. So they must be mapped together and so on.

*I prefer vectorized operations if it's possible and am looking for one.*

I tried doing:

```
d = {}
for i1, r1 in df_original.iterrows():
    for i2, r2 in df.iterrows():
        if r1[0] == r2[0]: 
            d[i2] = i1
print(d)
# {2: 0, 4: 1, 1: 2, 0: 3, 3: 4}
```

But this is very slow as I have the dataframes of the order of million rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `merge`:

```
(df_original.reset_index()
   .merge(df.reset_index(), on='text')
   .set_index('index_y')['index_x'].to_dict()
)
```

Out:

```
{2: 0, 4: 1, 1: 2, 0: 3, 3: 4}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

You can try `map`:

```
df['text'].map(df_original.reset_index().set_index('text')['index']).to_dict()
```

---

```
{0: 3, 1: 2, 2: 0, 3: 4, 4: 1}
```